Cherry-pick the same commit twice, then merge current branch to a new branch, the second cherry-pick does not work
I have cherry-picked the same commit twice, then merge current branch to a new branch, but the second cherry-pick does not work. Is that resonable?
I have a develop branch dev, and have a config commit on dev (like, switching to a different server) which may be applied multiple times later. Thus I try to use cherry pick to reapply it.
The first time cherry-pick works well. When I checkout to publish branch and merge dev into it,   it contains my cherry-pick modification. But a few days later when I repeat this command (cherry-pick the same commit, then merge it info publish), the publish branch does not contains the modification.
I repeat this operation in another simple test repo, and it seems like when u cherry-pick the same commit multiple times, only the first time really works (when merge, of course). But I cant google any authoritative doc or blog claiming these things.
Can anyone tell me if my opinion is right and why is that, or what wrong operation I have made to occur this behavior? THX

update: Maybe I dont explain the problem so well. I made a graph to explain the situation.
cherry-pick
I used "test1" to indicate the file status of the original commit. The problem is, when others modify it and merge it into master, and I want to reapply it to "test1", the first cherry-pick works fine, but the second cherry-pick seems to be ignored by merge operation. Maybe is some kind of merge mechanism to avoid reappling cherry-pick the same commit, I guess? But in my point of view, the dev newest commit has "test1" and master has "test1" modified, so they are different at the time of my second merge. I think both of them make sense.

update again: For those who have same confusion, found a blog explain simliar situation:Stop cherry-picking, start merging, Part 2: The merge conflict that never happened (but should have)
TLDR: Git Merge is a 3-way merge operation, compare HEAD and another commit with their common latest ancestor commit to judge modification, and my "test1" is the same as the common ancestor of dev and master
status, so it's not a "modification" of ancestor.
This is a merge mechanism, so this situation is not only about cherry-pick. But cherry-pick may increase the possibility of encountering the problem, I guess the better way to avoid it is, as the blod said, creating a new merge base.

Yes, it's expected from git to ignore already applied cherry-picks.

Yes, but i wonder why is that happening, is there any document talking about this behavior? Just curious about its inner mechanism

It would be useful to see a graph of the topology you're describing.

Regarding your update: cherry-pick is supposed to record a new commit with the given changes. It is supposed to record one commit. So it checks if it has already been applied. It has already been applied. So it doesn’t allow a second cherry-pick. The assumption of the tool is “I want this commit in the history”. It’s not “I want it applied whenever the diff allows it”. It’s not a repeatable action. It’s a one-time thing.

The best way to formulate a question is to state the assumptions you have contra the actual behavior.  Maybe with a reproduction script.

git-cherry-pick(1) applies the changes of a commit and then makes a new
commit.[1]

Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one
introduces, recording a new commit for each. This requires your
working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).

Given this commit:
commit 8e0da0f8fcee314cafd689d0a34bc330e257f4ae
Author: Kristoffer Haugsbakk <kristoffer@example.org>
Date:   2024-07-25 13:08:12 +0200

    Bye

diff --git a/greetings.txt b/greetings.txt
index e965047..c86756d 100644
--- a/greetings.txt
+++ b/greetings.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Hello
+Goodbye

You cherry-pick this commit and your greetings.txt file looks like
this.
Hello
Goodbye

Then you cherry-pick again. What would happen?
The diff doesn’t apply. The diff says that the last line should be:
Hello

But it is:
Goodbye

Furthermore Git even detects that this change already exists as one of
the commits in your history (the first cherry-pick). Or rather (in my
testing) you get a long message which includes:
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.

So Git does the right thing. Even if it isn’t describing it quite that well.
What is the alternative?
git-cherry-pick(1) applies a patch/diff. When applying a patch, the
target files need to be on a form such that the context of the patch
makes sense. But the state of the file does not make sense after a
cherry-pick; the patch wants to append Goodbye after the last line
Hello, but the last line is Goodbye because the patch was already
applied.
So there is nothing to do.
That’s how patch application works. An alternative could be to append
Goodbye to the end of the file after every cherry-pick, ignoring the
context of Hello being the last line. But now we are talking about
different semantics. And how would this generalize to other patches
which add or remove lines in the middle of files?
Notes

man git cherry-pick

